# How do I get the "old value" from a ReactiveCocoa signal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

If I'm using RACable like this:

```
[RACAbleWithStart(self.myProp) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
   // Do stuff

}];
```

How can can I access the old value of myProp (before the change the caused the signal to fire)? So I can access it like this:

```
[RACAbleWithStart(self.myProp) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
   // Do stuff
   id newValue = x;
   id oldValue = RAC_oldValue;
}];
```

Comment: Why not just use KVO?  Reactive Patterns deal with changes in x, not x.  `RACAbleWithStart()` doesn't do what you think it does: It creates a new signal, but populates it with the initial value of x, instead of waiting for a change to fire.  It doesn't remember anything, and it is not meant to give you "before and after" views of variable state.

Comment: @CodaFi I'm not expecting  RACAbleWithStart to give me the old value. I know it just makes the subscriber fire immediately. I'm asking this question to check if there is a way to access the old value, since ReactiveCocoa is designed as a easier to use wrapper around KVO.

Comment: Yes, it is a wrapper around KVO, but as I said, reactive patterns don't deal with old values, they deal with changes and new values.  If you need anything close to saving an old value, run your RACAbleWithStart() relationship through a RACReplaySubject (it's not perfect, but it'll work).

Comment: @CodaFi Put that in an answer with an explanation/example and I'll green check it.

Answer (score 4):

I have used this snippet with success:

```
[[object rac_valuesAndChangesForKeyPath:@"property" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld observer:self] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *tuple) {
    id newObject = tuple.first;
    NSDictionary *change = tuple.second;
    id oldObject = change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
}];
```

Source: [ReactiveCocoa documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ReactiveCocoa/2.4.7/Categories/NSObject+RACPropertySubscribing.html#//api/name/rac_valuesAndChangesForKeyPath:options:observer:)